# DataTables putting sort icon on a column which is specified as not having one

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

DataTables 1.10.18

I have defined the columns of my table as follows:

```
columns: [
          { "data": "expand_link", "name": "expand_link" },
          { "data": "date", "name": "date" },
          { "data": "col1", "name": "col1" },
          { "data": "col2", "name": "col2" },
          { "data": "col3", "name": "col3" },
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {"width": "5%", "targets": 0},
            {"width": "12%", "targets": 1},
            {"width": "35%", "targets": 2},
            {"width": "35%", "targets": 3},
            {"width": "12%", "targets": 4},
            {"orderable": false, "targets": [0, 2, 3, 4]} // Can order by Date only
        ],
```

The `{"orderable": false, "targets": [0, 2, 3, 4]}` means that it shouldn't be possible to order columns 0, 2, 3 and 4. This means that column 1 is orderable.

But when the table is rendered it's putting the up/down arrow icons on both columns 0 and 1:

[image]

The other columns (`col1...col3`, indexes 2 - 4) are ok as they don't include the sort icon, which is expected:

[image]

Why is it not working for column 0 (`expand_link`) when it's been specified in the js?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable#Comments – that comment is from 2014 and regarding v1.10.2, but it probably still applies I guess …?

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a user comment on https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable#Comments saying this,

> Note that in both examples given, a (disabled) sort control will still appear on column 0 unless you specify a default order on a different column using order.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21709/orderable-false-on-target-0-first-col-not-working-until-another-column-is-sorted explains the issue and fix in a bit more detail:

> After some more research, it looks like this is actually intended behavior because the table is by default sorted on the first column. So the indicator is there to show you that the table is sorted on that column. **In order to remove the indicator, you need to tell the table to default sort on a different column, or no column at all.**